# Basic url rewrite nginx error 500 or download

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, php

I am still unable to find a way to configure correctly my nginx server so that the urls of my website get rewrited the way I want it. It seems so easy (and it was, on my apache server), but I can't figure out where the problem is.

What I am trying to do is simple:
Have the browser display: "/portfolio/project/projectname"
while passing to server "/portfolio/project.php?project=projectname"

Here is my nginx custom.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name remitod.com www.remitod.com;

  root /var/www/html/remitod/;

  error_page 404 errors/404.html;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;


  rewrite ^/$ /portfolio last;
  rewrite ^/contact /contact.php last;

  #
  # Here is the line in question
  #
  rewrite ^/portfolio/project/(.+)$ /portfolio/project.php?project=$1 last;


  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

Right now, this is giving me a 500 error;
I tried changing the "last" at the end of my rewrite rule by "break", and what it does is it makes me download the php file!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is code `rewrite ^/portfolio/project/([^/.]+)(/?)$ /portfolio/project.php?project=$1;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still get a 500 error...

Comment: If config it should be in `location / { rewrite ^/portfolio/project/([^/.]+)(/?)$ /portfolio/project.php?project=$1; }`

Comment: Sorry, but still error 500...

Comment: Please try to remove these line and try again `rewrite ^/$ /portfolio last;
  rewrite ^/contact /contact.php last;` or move it to `location / { }`

Comment: Thanks it worked! But I also had a php error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually my nginx conf was right, I activated the error log as follows, and saw that it was a php error...

```
error_log /var/log/remitod.error.log;
```